# How to temporarily safely ignore files/changes from TFS

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, build-automation

Where I work we have a long build process that includes more than a dozen modules.  I work in module [A], and it often happens that code is checked into module [A] at the same time as code is checked into module [B] and [C] (this happens when a developer is working on cross module items).

The problem is that I periodically get latest on my module (necessary for other reasons relating to dev database schema concerns) and the new code can reference code in other modules ([B], [C], et..) which hasn't been built yet in our daily build.  I can pull down modules [B] and [C] and build them myself, but due to the configuration involved in our build process...this could take hours.

My solution so far has been to comment out the code which contains the functionality that isn't yet available, and then try to remember not to check those comments in when I am done with my work.  Is there a way to mark a file checkout (or a series of file checkouts) as temporary?

**Short Version**

**How do I mark part of my changes so that when I go to check-in that those changes (and not the rest of my changes) are ignored / undone?**

--Edit

**I can't use branching because of sync issues involving our dev database and our home brewed ORM.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found was to use a TFS feature called cloaking.  I can cloak a folder containing the offending code, and then I won't mistakenly check in code changes that I am trying to ignore.  It is still somewhat cumbersome in that I need to make sure to turn off cloaking once I am done, but at least I wont be erasing good code on accident.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: No. Sorry.

As a tip it sounds like you need to consider your branching strategy.  You may be best off creating a branch for your work so that you can work in isolation and then merge back your changes into the main branch when your work is complete.  Just remember to pull from main branch regularly after the build process completes so that your final merge is relatively pain free.

Comment: See the [Team Foundation Server 2010 Branching Guide](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/) to learn how easy branching can be with TFS 2010.

Comment: +1 for giving me an appropriate answer, but it is not a solution.  I will still have the same problems (that I will have to remember which changes were supposed to be temporary at the time of check-in).

Comment: No, you won't. If you set up feature branches correctly, you won't have to worry about changes to the other code until you need to integrate.

Comment: John is correct.  Branches isolate your code from others so you don't have to worry.  I've got a post on the branch per story pattern with TFS that may help - http://www.richard-banks.org/2011/02/branch-per-story-pattern-and-tfs.html

Comment: I can't isolate my code from the changes of other developers, because then our schema gen tool will not work on the development database.  I wouldn't be able to debug and sometimes this could leave me unable to compile (we have a code gen step based on xml files, and it deals with a home brewed ORM).  Branching won't work.  I specifically want to know how to mark pending changes so that they won't be checked in and will be discarded after check-in.

Comment: Again, I can't imagine the problem. The separate branch will simply be a different folder path. Does your ORM tool really care whether it's generating code into C:\Src vs. C:\Main\Src?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer remains the same.  You can't do what you want.  Maybe you should think about running the DB locally (if possible) so that you can remain isolated from what sounds like a shared database. If you can't do that, or run a second copy on another server, then you're stuck.  Sorry.

Comment: @John ...yes, it does expect a certain folder structure, though that isn't the problem.  The problem is that we don't have dedicated development servers.  I am not isolated from schema changes that are checked into the main trunk and our shop uses a lot of stored procedures (part of the 'ORM').  If I went to debug on a seperate branch, then I would get errors about missing stored procedures.

Comment: @Richard The deployment process for a dev server is quite costly  and only designed to be done from special batch servers, I can't perform that on a local machine.

Comment: The folder structure would be the same under C:\Main\Src as C:\Src is today. Also, if you used a Visual Studio Database Project for your development, most of your work could be offline. If you needed to test, you should certainly be able to deploy to a local server, create some test data, then test.

Comment: @John We did not use a visual studio database project for development.  It is not possible to deploy to a local server, as it involves generation of thousands of stored procs from 14+ modules (solutions) handled by a deployment server.

Comment: A database project deploys only the differences. You can also use "partial projects" so that you can limit your work to a subset of the database, while there will still be a project containing the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what TFS [Shelvesets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) are for? You can put all your changes into a shelveset to be commited later, then work on the existing code as things stand.

Shelvesets are a good way to have your changes waiting if you aren't ready to fully commit them yet.

Comment: No, the point is that I don't want to submit the changes later.  I want to make temporary changes that won't be submitted.

Comment: Yeah I know I mentioned that you could commit them later, but what I also meant by using Shelvesets was that you could also abandon them too.